# jQuery custom scrollbar script not working

Tags: jquery, html, css, scrollbar

This is my first post and I hope someone here can help.

I have tried 3 different sites on how to customize my scrollbar, and all was quite similar. But none of them seemed to customize the scrollbar...
The problem is this script:

```
$(window).load(function () {
    $(".demo").customScrollbar();
});
```

I get the message "*Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function*"

The problem appears with both perfect-scroll, jscrollpane and jQuery custom scrollbar by Rocketmind. There was a fourth place but i forgot.

All of these places require a script similar to above, and I've tried them all... Hope anyone can give me a solution for the problem.

I've made a version of JQuery custom scrollbar by Rocketmind [here](http://jsfiddle.net/marktheart/59jc24x5/) and you will also find link to original in the jsfiddle version...

Please help.. I'm desperate :(

Comment: If you don't put the script in the Window load option on the left, it work : http://jsfiddle.net/59jc24x5/1/

Comment: Hi Karl, thank you very much! But how do I make it so in my html? 
Not sure on how to make it "No wrap - in <head>" on my actual html

Comment: i did it like this on my actual site. Hope its understandable... It still doesn't work here even tho i put the script in top...
(http://www.marktheart.dk/final/ommig.html)

Answer (score 0):

Hmm why on load?

try:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
     $(".demo").customScrollbar();
});
```

it will run the script when the dom is ready

Comment: Hi ZetCoby, it was just an example of the 3 different tutorials I've allready followed and done, but still did'nt work. Your suggestion being the first one I tried... :/ thanks anyway!